# Lucene, stop word filter

Tags: lucene, stop-words

Hi i am using a StandardAnalyzer when indexing with stop words.

when i index the line

Microsoft Excel for Macintosh

it works well to search like this

and i use the same analyzer when searching as when indexing
+Microsoft +Excel +for +Macintosh

when i try to searhc like this

"Microsoft Excel for Macintosh" i get no result as it is transformed into "Microsoft Excel Macintosh"

Anyone have any idea why my result is 0 ?

//Trind

Comment: Since you use stopword filter during indexing, it removes "for" keyword from the index.

Comment: Yeah i understand that, but  when i want to search for "Microsoft Excel for Macintosh" i want to get a hit, how do i do that?

Comment: By using the same analyzers in the query part you can solve problem.

Comment: I am using same at both index and Quering, i am using StandardAnalyzer. if i however add slop 1 "Microsoft Excel for Macintosh"~1 i get results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StandardQueryParser.setEnablePositionIncrements(true);

did the trick.